# FATAL EXCEPTION: main. cuando pongo a correr mi proyecto se cierrra

Tags: java, android

Estoy programando una app para que las personas puedan aprender y recientemente agregue una función para que puedan iniciar sesión con Google, el problema es que de la nada dejo de correr correctamente, cuando la inicio en mi dispositivo me dice que está fallando y la consola me da este error :( .

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.offa/com.example.offa.ResgActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3620)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2183)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7617)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        at com.example.offa.ResgActivity.onCreate(ResgActivity.java:116)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7817)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7806)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1328)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3452)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3620) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2183) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7617) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11260 SIG: 9
```

Comment: y tu codigo donde esta?

Comment: *el problema es que de la nada dejo de correr correctamente* -> Ya lo dudo. El propio error te lo dice claramente. Estás intentando castear un ImageView a un SignInButton... No son lo mismo, y no puedes castear uno al otro sin más (Tal como has observado, si lo haces rompe :)) Te recomiendo que deshagas el cambio que hayas hecho para meter eso y lo intentes de otra manera... es difícil poder ayudarte realmente si no vemos el código, claro... Pero el error es **obvio y descriptivo**.

Comment: Gracias tu respuesto me ayudo mucho lindo dia, a si olvide colocar mi codigo :(